# How to upload HttpEntity.Chunked with Multipart.FormData with Akka-Http Client

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

When trying to upload a large file to a server as [chunked entity](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/scala/http/common/http-model.html#httpentity) in Multipart Form:

```
   val chunked = HttpEntity.Chunked.fromData(mimeType, sourceOfByteString)

Multipart.FormData(
      Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("downloadPath", HttpEntity(fileResourceRequest.downloadPath.path)),
      Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("fileSize", HttpEntity(fileResourceRequest.fileSize.toString)),
      Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("data", chunked, Map("filename" → "content"))
    ).toEntity()
```

I get this error:

> Type mismatch: expected BodyPartEntity, actual HttpEntity.Chunked

When adding a **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** [header](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/scala/http/common/http-model.html#http-headers) manually, Akka-http removes it, as per documentation.

I am able to successfully perform exactly the same Upload using curl

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer BB3F8B79384D08B9F268F21FF76ABFA" \
   -H "Transfer-Encoding:chunked" \
   -F "downloadPath=/user-data/media/dachi.png" \
   -F "fileSize=733830" \
   -F "data=@\"./dachi.png\";type=image/png;filename=\"dachi.png\"" \
 'http://0.0.0.0:8000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpEntity.IndefiniteLength](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/scala/http/common/http-model.html) as per documentation: